# Clarification on the use of fgetc

Tags: c, char, int, eof, fgetc

There is the following code from part of a function that I have been given:

```
char ch;
ch = fgetc(fp);
if (ch == EOF)
  return -1;
```

Where `fp` is a pointer-to-FILE/stream passed as a parameter to the function.

However, having checked the usage of `fgetc()`,`getc()` and `getchar()`, it seems that they all return type int rather than type char because EOF does not fit in the values 0-255 that are used in a char, and so is usually < 0 (e.g. -1). However, this leads me to ask three questions:

1. If `getchar()` returns int, why is `char c; c = getchar();` a valid usage of the function? Does C automatically type cast to char in this case, and in the case that `getchar()` is replaced with `getc(fp)` or `fgetc(fp)`?
2. What would happen in the program when `fgetc()` or the other two functions return EOF? Would it again try and cast to char like before but then fail? What gets stored in `ch`, if anything?
3. If EOF is not actually a character, how is `ch == EOF` a valid comparison, since EOF cannot be represented by a char variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If getchar() returns int, why is char c; c = getchar(); a valid usage of the function?*

It's not. Just because you can write and compiler (somehow) allows you to compile it, does not make a code valid.

*I believe the above answers all the questions.*

Just to add, in case `EOF` is returned, it cannot be stored in a `char`. Signedness of a `char` is implementation defined, thus, as per chapter 6.3.1.3, `C11`

> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>      the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>      subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>      until the value is in the range of the new type.60)
> 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>      result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Comment: Ok, so if I were to change `char ch;` to `int ch;`, then that code segment would run properly given a valid `fp`? In addition, if I wanted to use the int returned by `fgetc()` as a char in a string or in other functions, would it be valid to cast it to char so long as it is not EOF?

Comment: @ScottyN91 Yes, that's pretty much it.

Comment: Depending on whether or not char is signed and how EOF is implemented, using char might cause a variety of issues ranging from not being able to correctly read EOF, to one of the legal character values being interpreted as EOF.

Comment: "in case EOF is returned, it cannot be stored in a char" ---> Disagree.  When `char` is signed and `EOF == -1` of course `EOF` can be stored in a `char`.  The issues is not that `EOF` can or cannot be stored in a `char`,  a key issue is that one loses distinctiveness of 257 different results being stored in an 8-bit type.